# Error 'Impossible to guess date format' when trying to read RSS feed

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, rss, feed

What I'm trying to do is read an RSS feed that you can find [here](http://www.volley-avf.be/rss/rangschikking_rss.php?reeks=D%201%20P). I'm using Symfony2 and I want to use RSS Atom Bundle that you can find [here](https://github.com/alexdebril/rss-atom-bundle).

Now I have this:

```
$reader = $this->container->get('debril.reader');

// the feed you want to read
$url = 'http://www.volley-avf.be/rss/rangschikking_rss.php?reeks=D%201%20P';

$prevdate = new \DateTime('2013-12-16 15:17:27');

// now fetch its (fresh) content
$feed = $reader->getFeedContent($url, $prevdate);

// the $content object contains as many Item instances as you have fresh articles in the feed
$items = $feed->getItems();
```

The date ($prevdate in my case) is explained like this:

```
date : the last time you read this feed.
       This is useful to fetch only the articles which were published after your last hit.
```

I just want to read the file no matter what the date, so I try to insert a date long ago. But I always get this error: `Impossible to guess date format`.

When I try to use `new \DateTime('now');` it shows me the error 'Not Modified' what's correct .. Am I inserting a wrong datetime or something ... ?

**UPDATE:**
My DateTime object:

```
object(DateTime)[326]
   public 'date' => string '2013-12-16 15:17:27' (length=19)
   public 'timezone_type' => int 3
   public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Brussels' (length=15)
```

Comment: What does the date look like?

Comment: Added my DateTime object to my begin post!

Comment: What if you skip the $prevdate value? I believe it uses HTTP's if-Modified-Since header, which you probably don't want to add if you want *any* representation of the feed.

Comment: If I don't add a date to getFeedContent I get the following error: Argument 2 passed to Debril\RssAtomBundle\Protocol\FeedReader::getFeedContent() must be an instance of DateTime, none given